# Buffer overflow not working from different environment

Tags: buffer-overflow

I wrote my first buffer overflow exploit and it worked well with

```
./vulnerable $(cat payload)
```

but when I tried to launch it from a Python shell it didn't work

```
import os
os.system("./vulnerable $(cat payload)")
```

This does a segmentation fault. Can someone explain why? Is there a difference in the memory when it's launched in different environments?

Comment: Have you checked out how Python handles `os.system`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a reliable pivot, like `jmp esp` or are you jumping to a fixed address on the stack? If you're using the latter then your addresses are likely misaligned, and you should consider using a reliable pivot instead. If the former you'll need to inspect the crash by enabling coredumps and loding the core into a debugger.